# Select and update the additional property of NgRx entity using component store

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I have the below additional property

```
export interface MetricCreateState extends EntityState<UserSelectionListDto> {
    isLoading: boolean | undefined,
    isCreated: boolean | undefined,
    LoadConfigureMetric: boolean | undefined
}
```

Created a adaptor and initial property

```
export const adapter = createEntityAdapter<UserSelectionListDto>();
export const { selectAll, selectEntities } = adapter.getSelectors();

export const initialState: MetricCreateState = adapter.getInitialState({
    isLoading: false,
    isCreated: false,
    LoadConfigureMetric: false
});
```

I have a effect which load the data from the server side as

```
readonly getMetricOwners = this.effect((owners$: Observable<UserSelectionListDtoPagedResultDto>) => {
        this.setState((state) => adapter.setAll([], { ...state, isLoading: true }));
        return owners$.pipe(() => this.userServiceProxy.getUsersForSelection(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined).pipe(
            tap({
                next: (owners) => {
                    this.setState((state) => adapter.setAll(owners.items, { ...state, isLoading: false }));
                },
                error: (e) => {
                    this.setIsLoading(false);
                },
            }),
            catchError(() => EMPTY),
        ));
    });
```

Over here I am trying to update the single property

```
this.setState((state) => adapter.setAll([], { ...state, isLoading: true }));
```

Is this is the correct way to set the additional property of the entity? and how do we select the particular additioanl property. For example

- I want to update only `isLoading`
- I want to select only `isLoading`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, `setAll` also updates the entities collection

> Replace current collection with provided collection - [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter#adapter-collection-methods)

If you just want to update `isLoading`, you don't need to adapter because the adapter only handles the entities.

To update `isLoading`, you can simply do the following

```
{ ...state, isLoading: true }
```

or use the [`patch`](https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store/write#patchstate-method) method of ngrx component store

```
  this.componentStore.patchState({isLoading: true});
```